# Is there anyway to target a specific input field (via a selector) that the user has keyed up in?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to figure out a way if I can use javascript/jquery to target a specific input field a user has just keyed up in.

Comment: Please share your code that you have tried.

Comment: you mean something like `$('input').on('keyup', function(){ console.log($(this)); });`

Comment: added as an answer so you can accept something for this question

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes...def.  You kick so much ass, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generically target keyup events in all input fields, then access those using $(this)...

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){ 
    console.log($(this));
    // $(this) is the targeted element. Do what you wish with it.
});
```